# How can i know my gyro part number?& can i perform navigation without gyro sensor?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi..we are a graduation project team works on the turtlebot ..we already bought icreate robot and we designed the the rest plates of the turtlebot and we had the sdk as it is available and on our way to start calibration we found that we have to know our gyro part number which as the following tutorial [Calibrate Odometry and Gyro](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_calibration/Tutorials/Calibrate%20Odometry%20and%20Gyro) how can we know our gyro part number through our icreate robot base ??

answer was as Mr Ryan said :

> "The iCreate robot does not have a gyro built in. You'll need to purchase a power board separately"

Editing :-

```
**Am i still able to perform navigation and VSLAM without the gyro sensor ?**
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53815/how-can-i-know-my-gyro-part-number?&-can-i-perform-navigation-without-gyro-sensor-?/) by [Wafaay](https://answers.ros.org/users/3703/wafaay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2013-01-31

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2013-01-31**:
Do you have access to the gyro board? You probably have to look at the actual sensor, it's definitely written there. In [this board](http://store.iheartengineering.com/ihe-0200-0000-fa00.html), for instance, the gyro would be the silver square on the bottom right corner of the board.

**Comment by [Wafaay](https://answers.ros.org/users/3703/wafaay/) on 2013-01-31**:
that what i am talking about at the tutorial he is showing the board which i thought it is within the base and i don't have the access to it  but MR.Ryan said below that i have to buy it separately and i just noticed that "Only necessary if you have a Create base which is using an external gyro."

**Comment by [Wafaay](https://answers.ros.org/users/3703/wafaay/) on 2013-01-31**:
Question edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The iCreate robot does not have a gyro built in. You'll need to purchase a [power board separately](http://store.iheartengineering.com/ihe-0200-0000-fa00.html)

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2013-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wafaay](https://answers.ros.org/users/3703/wafaay/) on 2013-01-31**:
thank you i just noticed this statement on the tutorial "Only necessary if you have a Create base which is using an external gyro. " ..am i still able to navigate without calibration ?